# finding max in bunch of arrays in C

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, scanf

I have couple of questions.
I have a text file which contains these information

```
x0,x1,y0,y1
142,310,0,959
299,467,0,959
456,639,0,959
628,796,0,959
```

1. First, I want to read the text file using `fscanf` and get only the numbers into 4 arrays, `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, and `c4` by skipping the first line. So the final result will be

   ```
   c[1] = {142, 310, 0, 959}
   c[2] = {299, 467, 0, 959}
   c[3] = {456, 639, 0, 959}
   c[4] = {628, 796, 0, 959}
   ```
2. Then, for each `c[1]` to `c[4]`, I want to find the maximum integer and store it in [x, y] datatype. So for example in `c[1]`, the max will be `max[1]` = [310, 959].

Can anyone help? Other C solution other than using arrays to solve this problem is welcome as well.

In matlab, the code is

```
fid = fopen('foo.txt','r');
c = textscan(fid,'%d%d%d%d','delimiter',',','headerlines',1);
fclose(fid);
```

This will simply ignore the first line, then copy rest of numbers into arrays in matlab.
I would like to translate this code into C.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure I can help, post your code and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Umm why are you including 2 values in your max?

Comment: store values into STL vector and sort it. then the last two elements will be your maximum value.

Comment: How do you define your relation `~`? Does this mean similar in size?

Comment: You still havent pasted any code for your attempts to read the file, are you doing something like: `readline(fp);while(!feof(fp)){row++; fscanf ("%f,%f" .., &c[row][0],&c[row][1], ..) }; ..` ?

Comment: @jeong: Sorting the entire container to obtain some maximum (or minimum) values is overkill. It's much faster to use `std::partial_sort` or, even better, `std::nth_element`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I know..but in this case i assume that performance is not a big issue. Anyway thanks for partial_sort comment :)

Comment: @Argote: The two values are biggest x and y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not satsifying your question directly, I have provided an example of reading points using a `struct`, `std::istream` and `std::vector`.  These are preferred over `fscanf` and arrays.

```
struct Point
{
  unsigned int x;
  unsigned int y;

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Point& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Point& p)
{
  inp >> p.x;
  //Insert code here to read the separator character(s)
  inp >> p.y;
  return inp;
}

void Read_Points(std::istream& input, std::vector<Point>& container)
{
  // Ignore the first line.
  inp.ignore(1024, '\n');

  // Read in the points
  Point p;
  while (inp >> p)
  {
     container.push_back(p);
  }
  return;
}
```

The `Point` structure provides more readability, and IMHO, more versatility because you can declare other classes using a `Point`:

```
class Line
{
  Point start;
  Point end;
};

class Rectangle
{
  Point upper_left_corner;
  Point lower_right_corner;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Rectangle& r);
};
```

You can add methods for reading from a file using the `operator>>` for point:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& input, Rectangle& r)
{
  inp >> r.upper_left_corner;
  //Insert code here to read the separator character(s)
  inp >> r.lower_left_corner;
  return inp;
}
```

Arrays are a problem and can lead to nasty runtime errors such as buffer overruns.  Perfer `std::vector`, classes or structures to arrays.

Also, since `std::istream` is used, these structures and classes can be easily used with `std::cin` and files (`std::ifstream`):

```
  // Input from console
  Rectangle r;
  std::cin >> r;
```

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but I'm not sure how well this code will adapt to OP's use case of reading in two points at once and making a point from the max X and max Y of the two points. Also, instead of `while(inp>>p) {...}`, consider `container.insert(container.begin(), std::istream_iterator<Point>(input), std::istream_iterator<Point>())`. (I may have left a needed typename out of there and you might need extra parentheses to avoid the parser parsing the `istream_iterator` expressions as function declarations/pointers instead of temporary objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your

> Other format to solve this problem is welcome as well.

also means other language, Python code to solve this problem will be like this

```
fo = open('a.txt','r')
line = fo.readline() #ignore first line
max = [sorted(map(int,line.split(',')))[-2:] for line in fo]
```

and the result will be

> [[310, 959], [467, 959], [639, 959], [796, 959]]

Comment: Oh that's true I will edit that. I want it in C or C++ language. Sorry about that.